# Is there a way to check the interface link up / down on the Cisco ASA?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

Is there a way to check the interface link up / down on the ASA, such as on the console as follows:

```
Jul 25 02:00:15.268: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1, changed state to up
Jul 25 02:00:17.903: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1, changed state to down
Jul 25 02:00:18.903: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1, changed state to down
Jul 25 02:00:21.542: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2, changed state to up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I was looking for. . .

logging enable

※ When outputting on the console
logging console <0-7>

https://www.cisco.com/c/ja_jp/support/docs/security/pix-500-series-security-appliances/63884-config-asa-00.html

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is

```
Show interface Gi 1/0/1
```